# Gazebo vacuum_gripper setup

Tags: gazebo, ros2, gazebo-plugin, gripper

I am trying to add a vacuum gripper to my ROS2/Gazebo/Python project.
I have the following:

grip.xacro (note the plugin for gripper):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <xacro:arg name="link1_x" default="0.076"/>
    <xacro:arg name="link1_y" default="0"/>
    <xacro:arg name="link1_z" default="0.076"/>
    <xacro:arg name="link1_joint_x" default="0.04"/>
    <xacro:arg name="link1_joint_z" default="0.008"/>

    <link name="gripper_link_base">
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <origin rpy="1.571 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
            <inertia ixx="0.02216" ixy="5.8e-06" ixz="6.2e-06" iyy="0.02"
                iyz="-5.3e-05"
                izz="0.02"/>
        </inertial>
        <!-- collision>
            <origin rpy="1.571 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file:///$(find arm_04)/description/meshes/gripA/gripA_0.stl" 
                    scale="0.004 0.004 0.004" />                
            </geometry>
        </collision -->            
        <visual>
            <origin rpy="1.571 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file:///$(find arm_04)/description/meshes/gripA/gripA_0.stl" 
                    scale="0.004 0.004 0.004" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="yellow">
                <color rgba="1 1 0 1"/>
            </material>                  
        </visual>
    </link>

    <link name="gripper_link_left_1">
        <contact>
            <plugin name="gripper_link_left_1_contact_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_contact.so"/>
        </contact>    
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <origin xyz="4e-06   -0.001     0.082"/>
            <inertia ixx="3.9" ixy="-0.11" ixz="-8e-9" iyy="0.6" iyz="7e-9" izz="3.7"/>
        </inertial>
        <collision>
            <origin rpy="1.571 0 0" xyz="-$(arg link1_x) $(arg link1_y) $(arg link1_z)" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file:///$(find arm_04)/description/meshes/gripA/gripA_L_1.stl" 
                    scale="0.004 0.004 0.004" />
                <!-- cylinder radius="0.08" length="0.2"/ -->
            </geometry>
        </collision>            
        <visual>
            <origin rpy="1.571 0 0" xyz="-$(arg link1_x) $(arg link1_y) $(arg link1_z)" />
            <!-- origin rpy="1.571 0 0" xyz="-0.036 0 0.038" /-->
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file:///$(find arm_04)/description/meshes/gripA/gripA_L_1.stl" 
                    scale="0.004 0.004 0.004" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="red">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>                  
        </visual>

        <surface>
            <friction>
                <ode>
                    <mu>1.0</mu>
                    <mu2>1.0</mu2>
                </ode>
            </friction>
            <contact>
                <ode>
                    <kp>100</kp>
                    <kd>100</kd>
                    <min_depth>0.005</min_depth>
                    <max_vel>0.0</max_vel>
                </ode>
            </contact>
        </surface>        

    </link>        

    <joint name="gripper_joint_left_1" type="prismatic">
        <parent link="gripper_link_base" />
        <child link="gripper_link_left_1" />
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-$(arg link1_joint_x) $(arg link1_y) $(arg link1_joint_z)" />
        <!-- origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.036 0 -0.04" / -->
        <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
        <limit effort="100" lower="-0.04" upper="0.1" velocity="0.05"/>
        <dynamics damping="60.0" friction="4.0" />
    </joint>     

    <link name="gripper_link_right_1">
        <contact>
            <plugin name="gripper_link_right_1_contact_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_contact.so"/>
        </contact>    
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <origin xyz="4e-06   -0.001     0.082"/>
            <inertia ixx="3.9" ixy="0.1" ixz="8e-9" iyy="0.6" iyz="7e-9" izz="3.7"/>
        </inertial>
        <collision>
            <origin rpy="1.571 0 0" xyz="$(arg link1_x) $(arg link1_y) $(arg link1_z)" />
            <geometry>
                <!-- cylinder radius="0.08" length="0.2"/ -->
                <mesh filename="file:///$(find arm_04)/description/meshes/gripA/gripA_R_1.stl" 
                    scale="0.004 0.004 0.004" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>            
        <visual>
            <origin rpy="1.571 0 0" xyz="$(arg link1_x) $(arg link1_y) $(arg link1_z)" />
            <!-- origin rpy="1.571 0 0" xyz="-0.036 0 0.038" /-->
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file:///$(find arm_04)/description/meshes/gripA/gripA_R_1.stl" 
                    scale="0.004 0.004 0.004" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="red">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>                  
        </visual>

        <surface>
            <friction>
                <ode>
                    <mu>1.0</mu>
                    <mu2>1.0</mu2>
                </ode>
            </friction>
            <contact>
                <ode>
                    <kp>100</kp>
                    <kd>100</kd>
                    <min_depth>0.005</min_depth>
                    <max_vel>0.0</max_vel>
                </ode>
            </contact>
        </surface>        

    </link>        

    <joint name="gripper_joint_right_1" type="prismatic">
        <parent link="gripper_link_base" />
        <child link="gripper_link_right_1" />
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="$(arg link1_joint_x) $(arg link1_y) $(arg link1_joint_z)" />
        <!-- origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.036 0 -0.04" / -->
        <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
        <limit effort="100" lower="-0.1" upper="0.04" velocity="0.05"/>
        <dynamics damping="60.0" friction="4.0" />

        <!-- Mimic the movement of gripper_joint_left_1 -->
        <!-- mimic joint="gripper_joint_left_1" multiplier="-1" offset="0" / -->

    </joint>

    <plugin name='vacuum_gripper' filename='libgazebo_ros_vacuum_gripper.so'>

      <ros>
        <!-- Add a namespace -->
        <!-- namespace>/demo</namespace -->

        <!-- Remap service name -->
        <remapping>switch:=custom_switch</remapping>

        <!-- Remap publisher topic name -->
        <remapping>grasping:=custom_grasping</remapping>
      </ros>

      <!-- Link associated with gripper -->
      <link_name>gripper_link_right_1</link_name>

      <!-- Max and min distance to attract entities -->
      <max_distance>10.0</max_distance>

      <!-- List of entities to be not attracted by the gripper -->
      <fixed>ground_plane</fixed>
      <!-- fixed>wall</fixed -->

    </plugin>

    <!-- Gazebo colors -->

    <gazebo reference="gripper_link_base">
        <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
    </gazebo>
    <gazebo reference="gripper_link_left_1">
        <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
    </gazebo>     
    <gazebo reference="gripper_link_right_1">
        <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
    </gazebo>           

</robot>
```

Then from the code I have to switch this thing on and off. I understand (correct me please if I am wrong) that it is done by calling service, so I have created a client:

self.init():

```
# Create a client for the vacuum gripper's switch service
self.vacuum_switch_client = self.create_client(SetBool, 'custom_switch')
while not self.vacuum_switch_client.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=1.0):
    print('Service not available, waiting...')
```

However, when I run

```
$ ros2 service list
```

I do not see any new services showing after I add the plugin, accordingly, it all stops at infinite

```
Service not available, waiting...
Service not available, waiting...
Service not available, waiting...
Service not available, waiting...
Service not available, waiting...
```

So, apparently, I do something wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Quite intimidating, really. The plugin has to be inside the `<gazebo>` tag...